# Standard error logic

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, econometrics

Obviously the closer the standard error to zero the better. However, what if the values the in which the standard errors are from are extremely large and the standard errors are much higher than zero but proportionately small.

For example:

What if you have a model with a slope coefficient of 0.5 and the standard error was 0.05 and another model with a slope coefficient of 1000 and a standard error of 10.

Would the latter be considered a better standard error?

Comment: The better model is the model that is more correct. The standard error is meant to reflect the uncertainty in the parameter estimator. We don't want a model that makes it seem that the estimator is very precise, if in fact, for example if there are violations of model assumptions, the estimator may not be reliable at all. It is unclear whether you mean the theoretical or estimated standard error here; for sure if our estimator is indeed imprecise, we *want* the estimated standard error to be large so that we can see this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This could be where the p-value comes in.

In the first case, the estimated parameter is $10$ standard errors away from zero. This will result in a small p-value.

In the second case, the estimated parameter is $100$ standard errors away from zero. This will result in an even smaller p-value.

To some extent, this depends on the sample size (at least for t-stats, but not for z-stats), though that should not be much of an issue for so dramatic of a difference as $10$ and $100$.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I am new to stats. Is there a rule of thumb for how many standard errors from zero is good/acceptable?

Comment: It depends on your chosen $\alpha$-level ($0.05$ is common, for better or for worse), and your sample size. For a decent number of degrees of freedom, two standard errors roughly corresponds to a p-value of $0.05$. You can get finer details by consulting software or t-charts.